# Transparent glitches while drawing GIF

Tags: c++, direct2d

I wrote some solution to draw gifs, using [Direct2D GIF sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/wic/wicanimatedgif/WicAnimatedGif.cpp):

```
// somewhere in render loop

IWICBitmapFrameDecode* frame = nullptr;
IWICFormatConverter* converter = nullptr;
gifDecoder->GetFrame(current_frame, &frame);

if (frame)
{
    d2dWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&converter);

    if (converter)
    {
        ID2D1Bitmap* temp = nullptr;

        converter->Initialize(frame, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
            WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.f, WICBitmapPaletteType::WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom);

        tar->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(converter, NULL, &temp);

        scale->SetValue(D2D1_SCALE_PROP_SCALE, D2D1::Vector2F(1, 1));
        scale->SetInput(0, temp);

        target->DrawImage(scale);

        SafeRelease(&temp);
    }
}
SafeRelease(&frame);
SafeRelease(&converter);
```

Where `gifDecoder` is obtained this way:

```
d2dWICFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(pathToGif, NULL, GENERIC_READ, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &gifDecoder);
```

[image]

But in my program almost with all gifs, all frames, except the first one, for some reason have horizontal transparent lines. Obviously, when I view the same gif in browser or in another program there are no that holes.

I tried to change pixel format, pallet type, but that glitches are still there.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Those aren't "glitches" - they are "pixels that don't need to be updated".  Think of them as transparent pixels.  To correctly render any frame from an animated gif, you must first render all the frames that come before it.

Comment: @DrewDormann, seems to be difficult - obviously on each render call I clear the render target. So, in case of gif, after drawing a frame, I need to store it and then draw first in before next frame?

Comment: That would be one valid approach.

Comment: @DrewDormann I just wrote the solution according to Your explanation, and, it works fine, but only when the gif is not actually supposed to have transparency. If there are alpha pixels (in the original frames images themselves) then, because before each frame I draw superposition of all previous ones, it is just a mess. What to do in that case? How do I deal with alpha pixels that I called glitches and “real” alpha pixels?

Comment: Each gif frame has merging mode - either replace (entire) previous frame or update (some pixels of) previous frame. So instead of rendering all previous frames directly on the render target you need create a dedicated texture to be updated frame by frame and then render this texture on your render target.

Comment: @user7860670, yeah, I am currently finishing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic steps:

1. On image load, in case of gif, for caching purposes store not all frames as ready to draw `ID2D1Bitmap`s but only the image's decoder. Every time decode the frame, get bitmap and draw it. At least, at first animation loop frames bitmaps and metadata (again, for each frame) can be cached.
2. For each gif create compatible target with the size of gif screen (obtained from metadata) for composing.
3. Compose animation on render: get metadata for current frame -> if current frame has disposal = true, clear compose target -> draw current frame to compose target (even if disposal true) -> draw compose target to render target,
4. Note, that frames may have different sizes and **even offsets**.

Approximate code:

```
ID2D1DeviceContext *renderTarget;

class GIF
{
      ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget *compose;

      IWICBitmapDecoder *decoder; // it seems like precache all frames costs too much time, it will be faster to obtain each frame each time (maybe cache during first loop)
      float naturalWidth; // gif screen width
      float naturalHeight; // gif screen height

      int framesCount;
      int currentFrame;
      unsigned int lastFrameEpoch;

      int x;
      int y;
      int width; // image width needed to be drawn
      int height; // image height

      float fw; // scale factor width;
      float fh; // scale factor height

      GIF(const wchar_t *path, int x, int y, int width, int height)
      {
           // Init, using WIC obtain here image's decoder, naturalWidth, naturalHeight
           // framesCount and other optional stuff like loop information
           // using IWICMetadataQueryReader obtained from the whole image,
           // not from zero frame

           compose = nullptr;
           currentFrame = 0;
           lastFrameEpoch = epoch(); // implement Your millisecond function

           Resize(width, height);
      }

      void Resize(int width, int height)
      {
           this->width = width;
           this->height = height;

           // calculate scale factors
           fw = width / naturalWidth; 
           fh = height / naturalHeight;

           if(compose == nullptr)
           {
                 renderTarget->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(D2D1::SizeF(naturalWidth, naturalHeight), &compose);
                 compose->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(0,0,0,0));
           }
      }

      void Render()
      {
           IWICBitmapFrameDecode* frame = nullptr;
           decoder->GetFrame(currentFrame, &frame);

           IWICFormatConverter* converter = nullptr;
           d2dWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&converter);

           converter->Initialize(frame, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
                WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.f, WICBitmapPaletteType::WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom);

            IWICMetadataQueryReader* reader = nullptr;
            frame->GetMetadataQueryReader(&reader);

            PROPVARIANT propValue;
            PropVariantInit(&propValue);

            char disposal = 0;
            float l = 0, t = 0; // frame offsets (may have)

            HRESULT hr = S_OK;

            reader->GetMetadataByName(L"/grctlext/Delay", &propValue);
            if (SUCCEEDED((propValue.vt == VT_UI2 ? S_OK : E_FAIL)))
            {
                UINT frameDelay = 0;
                UIntMult(propValue.uiVal, 10, &fr);
                frameDelay = fr;

                if (frameDelay < 16)
                {
                    frameDelay = 16;
                }

                if(epoch() - lastFrameEpoch < frameDelay)
                {
                       SafeRelease(&reader);
                       SafeRelease(&frame);
                       SafeRelease(&converter);
                       return;
                }
            }

            

            if (SUCCEEDED(reader->GetMetadataByName(
                L"/grctlext/Disposal",
                &propValue)))
            {
                hr = (propValue.vt == VT_UI1) ? S_OK : E_FAIL;
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    disposal = propValue.bVal;
                }
            }

            PropVariantClear(&propValue);

            {
                hr = reader->GetMetadataByName(L"/imgdesc/Left", &propValue);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = (propValue.vt == VT_UI2 ? S_OK : E_FAIL);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        l = static_cast<FLOAT>(propValue.uiVal);
                    }
                    PropVariantClear(&propValue);
                }
            }

            {
                hr = reader->GetMetadataByName(L"/imgdesc/Top", &propValue);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = (propValue.vt == VT_UI2 ? S_OK : E_FAIL);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        t = static_cast<FLOAT>(propValue.uiVal);
                    }
                    PropVariantClear(&propValue);
                }
            }
    
            renderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(converter, NULL, &temp);


            compose->BeginDraw();
            if (disposal == 2)
                compose->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(0, 0, 0, 0));
        
            auto ss = temp->GetSize();
            compose->DrawBitmap(temp, D2D1::RectF(l, t, l + ss.width, t + ss.height));
            
            compose->EndDraw();

            ID2D1Bitmap* composition = nullptr;
            compose->GetBitmap(&composition);

            // You need to create scale effect to have antialised resizing
            scale->SetValue(D2D1_SCALE_PROP_SCALE, D2D1::Vector2F(fw, fh));
            scale->SetInput(0, composition);

            auto p = D2D1::Point2F(x, y);

            renderTarget->DrawImage(iscale, p); 

             SafeRelease(&temp);                
             SafeRelease(&composition);
             SafeRelease(&reader);
             SafeRelease(&frame);
             SafeRelease(&converter);
      }
}*gif[100] = {nullptr};


inline void Render()
{
      renderTarget->BeginDraw();

      for(int i = 0; i < 100 && gif[i] != nullptr; i++)
         gif[i]->Render();

      renderTarget->EndDraw();
}
```